# Add Last Linked list

Tags: c++

I have 2 functions, AddLast Linked List:

```
void Insert_Last1(Node *&pNode, int x) {
    Node *P;

    P = CreateNode(x);
    if (pNode == NULL) {
        pNode = P;
    }
    else {
        //Node *temp = new Node;
        //temp = pNode;
        while (pNode->pNext != NULL) {
            pNode = pNode->pNext;
        }
        pNode->pNext = P;
    }
}


void Insert_Last2(Node *&pNode, int x) {
    Node *P;

    P = CreateNode(x);
    if (pNode == NULL) {
        pNode = P;
    }
    else {
        Node *temp = new Node;
        temp = pNode;
        while (temp->pNext != NULL) {
            temp = temp->pNext;
        }

        temp->pNext = P;
    }
}
```

What is the role of variable temp in `Insert_Last2`?
What do have influence with variable `pNode`?
Why when I replace `temp` (with a `pNode` in `Insert_Last1`) the result is wrong?

```
Input: 1 2 3 4 5  
Insert_Last1 output: 4 5  
Insert_Last2 output: 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: It seems like you need to understand pointers better, in the first case you are traversing the list using head pointer and i guess you are not saving it elsewhere, while in second you are using temp to traverse the list which keeps the pointer to head intact.

Comment: [Rubber Ducky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) wants you to explain `Node *temp = new Node;
        temp = pNode;` to it.

Comment: One of the greatest untaught secrets of programming is that [Debugging Software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) exists. A debugger allows you to control the execution of your program and see the contents of the variables. You can step through the program line by line and watch what happens. This ability is utterly invaluable for spotting where program execution deviates from your expectations. Deviations are either bugs in the program or bugs in your thinking. Both cases need to be fixed.